# Regexp, remove part in the middle of a url - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I'm a beginner at regexp in javascript and getting a bit confused :
here's the url:

```
https://www.example.com.au/media/catalog/product/cache/ca6a1abe4cdf1032b0397780507d1aa8/h/u/hugh_camel_1_web.jpg
```

I would like to remove the id of the product `ca6a1abe4cdf1032b0397780507d1aa8/` but am getting a bit dizzy looking and testing all the examples I could find (with no success).

Expected output :

```
https://www.example.com.au/media/catalog/product/cache/h/u/hugh_camel_1_web.jpg
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Any detailed explanation of the regex would also be awesome.

Comment: does it have to be regex? I think using string split would be simpler if the string that you want to get rid of is always in the same position

Comment: If you aren't using regex, a solution might be `'https://www.example.com.au/media/catalog/product/cache/ca6a1abe4cdf1032b0397780507d1aa8/h/u/hugh_camel_1_web.jpg'.split('/').filter(i=>i.length < 30).join('/')`

Comment: @GlenK, yes it has to be regex.

Comment: @quicVO I need to use regex but am still interested by your method, can you explain the i.length part please ? cheers

Comment: I removed the piece of the url with characters longer than 30 per slash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```js
const url = "https://www.example.com.au/media/catalog/product/cache/ca6a1abe4cdf1032b0397780507d1aa8/h/u/hugh_camel_1_web.jpg";
const regex = /(\product\/cache\/)[^\/]*\//;
let result = url.replace(regex, '$1');
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com.au/media/catalog/product/cache/h/u/hugh_camel_1_web.jpg
```

Explanation of regex:

- `(\product\/cache\/)` - capture group for `/product/cache/`

  - Note: You could use a positive lookbehind, but that is not yet universally supported by all browsers
- `[^\/]*` - scan over everything until just before next `/`
- `\/` - scan over `/`
- in the replace use just the capture group, and ignore the scanned pattern after that: `'$1'`

**EDIT:** Here is the positive lookbehind version that does not capture a group, e.g. the replacement can be an empty string `''`.

```js
const url = "https://www.example.com.au/media/catalog/product/cache/ca6a1abe4cdf1032b0397780507d1aa8/h/u/hugh_camel_1_web.jpg";
const regex = /(?<=\product\/cache\/)[^\/]*\//;
let result = url.replace(regex, '');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer (I don't know why you got a downvote by the way...) unfortunately, even though it seems to be working in your snippet, when I use it or test it it seems to also be deleting catalog/product/

Comment: Ok my bad! I just misunderstood your last point :) It works perfect, thanks a lot !

Comment: See also note about positive lookbehind

Comment: yes I read about that and actually tried it a bit but I need to train on regex still

Comment: See **EDIT** with positive lookbehind version